# How to improve the encode quality of Android MediaCodec in low bitrate?

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, glsurfaceview

I use the Surface as the MediaCodec input and encode the camera preview frame. There is a problem that the video quality is bad if the bitrate under 1000 kbps especially when shake the android phone.

Any suggestions about improving the encoding quality of Android MediaCodec ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @fadden, Could please give me some suggestions ? Thanks.

Comment: "1000 Kbps" is about 150KBps, or 1x CD-ROM speed. I would expect that you'd need to be encoding at about 320x240, with infrequent I-frames, to make that look good -- but with very infrequent I-frames it might get a bit nasty if there's a lot of movement. You may want to try devices with chipsets from different manufacturers (e.g. Qualcomm vs. Samsung) to see if some devices perform better at lower bit rates, or have image stabilization features that reduce the movement in the output.

Comment: @fadden Thanks for your response. What's the value about `infrequent I-frames`? How much more appropriate about `MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL`  ?

Comment: On some devices, the values of `KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL` and `KEY_FRAME_RATE` combine to determine the GOP size. The farther apart they are, the less often you'll have large I-frames in your stream, so more bits can be spent on the prediction frames. Depending on the amount of motion in your video, this can be counter-productive quality-wise, so you'll need to experiment.